# Should std::atomic variables use "normal" syntax or "load" and "store"?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

If I have an atomic variable, e.g.,

```
std::atomic<int> x;
```

and I want to perform reads and writes on it, I can use the "normal" syntax, e.g.,

```
std::cout << x;       // read from x
x = 5;                // write to x
```

I can also use the explicit `load` and `store` member functions:

```
std::cout << x.load();       // read from x
x.store(5);                  // write to x
```

I've seen recommendations by people like Andrei Alexandrescu and Anthony Williams to use only the explict `load` and `store` forms, presumably because the "normal" forms don't emphasize that the variables are atomic. That seems almost like a form of Hungarian notation. Is there an emerging convention on the syntax to use when reading and writing atomics?

Comment: Do you have an actual, real-world code example where this question is relevant? I wonder if most uses of atomics don't come paired with relaxed ordering anyway, since they kind of people who'd use atomics are also the ones who'd want to exploit every possible optimization...

Comment: I'd think a common example would be use of an atomic<bool> as a flag used by one thread to indicate the availability of data for use by another thread. For example, to indicate that a data structure's initialization has been completed by one thread, and the data structure is now ready for exclusive use by a second thread. Because only one thread at a time accesses the data structure, there is no need for a mutex.

Comment: That would be a classic release-acquire pair, though...

Comment: Yes, but it works fine with SC. My feeling is that there's no reason to veer off into non-sequential consistency unless there's a really compelling reason.

Comment: If you only ever use sequential consistency, then I don't see anything wrong with just using plain operators. But it's really a matter of opinion...

Answer (score 10):

Several operations are overloaded to "do what you think", and to do this with sequentially consistent memory ordering. So:

- `int n = x;` is the same as `int n = x.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`, and
- `x = 1` is the same as `x.store(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst)`.

However, if you want any kind of relaxed memory ordering, you need to use the explicit member function, e.g. `int n = x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)`.

The idea is that "natural" looking code will generally be correct (recall the "sequentially consistent for data-race-free programs" execution model), but riskier, more aggressive operations are available – they just have to be explicit.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is about the common case when SC is desired, so both syntaxes can be used.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe: If you only use the "normal" syntax, you probably won't have mistakes *specific* to memory ordering, so they seem fine. Consult your company's house style, though. That said, if you do actually need atomic variables, chances are you'll have release-acquire pairs and will want to take advantage of relaxed ordering.